# How do we know the pdf of $X_{max}$ for a uniform distribution?

Tags: uniform-distribution, parameter-estimation

How do we know the pdf of $X_{max}$?

We have a sample of size $n=6$ from a uniform distribution of the interval $[0,\theta]$. Let $\hat{\theta}=X_{max}$ be the estimator of $\theta$.

(a) Given $\theta=3$ find the probability that $\hat{\theta}$ falls within 0.2 of $\theta$;

(b) Calculate the probability from (a) when sample size $n=3$.

Recall, that
$$\text{pdf of $X_{max}$ is $f_{X_{max}}(x)=\frac{n}{\theta^n}x^{n-1}$, $EX_{max} = \frac{n}{n+1}\theta$, and $\operatorname{Var}(X_{max})=\frac{n\theta^2}{n+2}-\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^2\theta^2.$}$$

Original problem image:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/74eus.png

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking how the formula for the pdf of $X_{max}$ was derived, but it's kind of unclear.

Comment: Yes, I am - I know how to solve the problem otherwise

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can derive the pdf by calculating the cdf and taking the derivative. The probability that $X_{max}\le x$ for $x$ between $0$ and $\theta$ is the probability that all $n$ measurements fall between $0$ and $x$. But for a single measurement, this is $\frac{x}{\theta}$. The probability $n$ independent measurements fall between $0$ and $x$ is then $\left(\frac{x}{\theta}\right)^n=\frac{x^n}{\theta^n}$. Now we take the derivative to find the pdf, namely $\frac{nx^{n-1}}{\theta^n}$.